# recursively chmod files using RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, recursion, iterator, filesystems, chmod

I'm trying to build a function that recursively set files or/and directories permissions of a given path, using both `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` php classes. but things dont seem to work, so i will be happy to receive your help. thanks!

```
function rSetPerms($path ,$filemode = '0644', $foldermode = '0705')
{ 

    if(!is_dir($path) and !file_exists($path)) return false;

        $paths = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($paths as $item) {
            if ($item->isDir()) 
            {
                if (!@ chmod($item->__toString(), octdec($foldermode))) return false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                if (!@ chmod($item->__toString(), octdec($filemode))) return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Take away the `@` error suppression, and see what warnings (if any) are being issued.  Remember to have `error_reporting` and `display_errors` configuration options set appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that your php script needs to be executed as root in order to chmod files.

You could also just use `sudo chmod -R` to recursively apply chmod to the files in a directory and its sub-directories.

Comment: thks for your answer, but i need it to run on all avelable platforms, not only unix/linux systems. normally on a webserver, the filesystem owner is the apache user/group, not the root. so this virtual user have the rights to change files permission in the document root.